# Mouse click object in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simple application that drawing Ellipse, lines, and rectangles.

Code:

```
 private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        if(figura == "linia")
        {
            linia = new Line
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(linia);
        }

        if (figura == "kwadrat")
        {
            rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPoint.X);

            canvas.Children.Add(rect);
        }

        else if (figura == "kolko")
        {
            circ = new Ellipse
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(circ, startPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(circ, startPoint.X);

            canvas.Children.Add(circ);
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rect == null && circ == null && linia == null)
            return;

        var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
        var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

        var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
        var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

        if(figura == "linia")
        {
            linia.X1 = startPoint.X;
            linia.Y1 = startPoint.Y;
            linia.X2 = pos.X;
            linia.Y2 = pos.Y;
        }

        if (figura == "kwadrat")
        {
            rect.Width = w;
            rect.Height = h;

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
        }

        if (figura == "kolko")
        {
            circ.Width = w;
            circ.Height = h;

            Canvas.SetLeft(circ, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(circ, y);
        }
    }
    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        rect = null;
        circ = null;
    }
```

Now i want to do something with object like resize, move etc. When they are clicked by mouse. I dont know how i can find object that was clicked by mouse. Can you help me ?

Comment: Before doing everything on your own. Consider using the [Thumb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.aspx) control, which works perfectly for resizing and moving objects. Besides that, why does the canvas need to know about the items? You should check what a Panel and an ItemsControl is.

Comment: Read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`e.OriginalSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) will get you the control that was actually clicked.

Comment: Actually OriginalSource will give you the original element in complex controls or user controls.  For example, if you click a Button then OriginalSource might be the Border element or the ButtonChrome element, but Source will always be the Button itself.

Comment: Its fine, when i click on object some action is done, but if. If i try change X1 for line that was click: e.OriginalSource.X1 = 50; it is an error.

Comment: @Finchsize Did you forget to cast it? The property returns an object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the RoutedEvent.Source property.

```
if (e.Source is Rectangle)
{
}
else if (e.Source is Ellipse)
{
}
else if (e.Source is Line)
{
}
```